# How to disable warnings in specific location?

Tags: xcode, clang, warnings, precompiled-headers

To disable warnings in all files, i'm using following precompiler header:

```
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmacro-redefined"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-designated-initializers"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wshorten-64-to-32"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincompatible-pointer-types"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-selector-name"

#endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */
```

I need to disable warnings for files, located in specific folder, for example `$(SRCROOT)/wrapper/`. How can i do that?